# GnuPG: gpa.exe hangs when I click on "smartcards" AND scdaemon cannot recognise SC-HSM 4K

Tags: encryption, gnupg, smartcard, token, smime

https://dev.gnupg.org/T6097

I am trying to get GnuPG to work with my SmartCard-HSM 4K on Windows, using the GP4Win bundle.

Kleopatra doesn't recognise the SC-HSM 4K at all, even though, it *does* recognise the YubiKey 5 NFC in *both* PIV and OpenPGP Card apps.

When trying to use the GPA.exe alternative, it freezes when I click on the "smartcards" button; not sure if it's related.

Trying to debug this, using CMD:

```
scdaemon --server
serialno
```

I get the following result:

```
scdaemon[xxxxx]: detected reader 'ACS ACR38U 0' scdaemon[xxxxx]:
reader slot 0: not connected scdaemon[xxxxx]: pcsc_control failed:
invalid PC/SC error code (0x1) scdaemon[xxxxx]:
pcsc_vendor_specific_init: GET_FEATURE_REQUEST failed: 65547
scdaemon[xxxxx]: reader slot 0: active protocol: T1 scdaemon[xxxxx]:
slot 0: ATR=3bde18ff8191fe1fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
scdaemon[xxxxx]: error parsing PrKDF record: Invalid object
scdaemon[xxxxx]: no supported card application found: Invalid object S
PINCACHE_PUT 0// ERR 100696144 No such device <SCD>
```

Below I am including my configuration files.

scdaemon.conf

```
###+++--- GPGConf ---+++###
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
disable-ccid
###+++--- GPGConf ---+++### 09/06/y22 23:29:33 GTB Daylight Time
# GPGConf edited this configuration file.
# It will disable options before this marked block, but it will
# never change anything below these lines.

#pcsc-shared
```

I have tried all possible combinations with `disable-ccid` and `pcsc-shared` and nothing works.

gpgagent.conf

```
###+++--- GPGConf ---+++###
enable-extended-key-format
ignore-cache-for-signing
no-allow-external-cache
no-allow-loopback-pinentry
grab
pinentry-timeout 10
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
ssh-fingerprint-digest SHA384
###+++--- GPGConf ---+++### 18/04/y22 07:30:51 GTB Daylight Time
# GPGConf edited this configuration file.
# It will disable options before this marked block, but it will
# never change anything below these lines.

enable-putty-support
enable-ssh-support
use-standard-socket
default-cache-ttl 600
max-cache-ttl 7200
```

gpgsm.conf

```
###+++--- GPGConf ---+++###
auto-issuer-key-retrieve
enable-crl-checks
enable-ocsp
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
verbose
include-certs -1
cipher-algo AES256
###+++--- GPGConf ---+++### 01/04/y22 19:10:26 GTB Daylight Time
# GPGConf edited this configuration file.
# It will disable options before this marked block, but it will
# never change anything below these lines.
```

I was never able to get the SC-HSM to work with GnuPG, even though it is supposedly supported. I haven't played with anything else than scdaemon.conf, but, as far as I can tell, the SC-HSM didn't work even with the defaults on a fresh install.

The card otherwise works nicely with everything else.

Comment: What is the output of `gpg --card-status`?

Comment: `gpg: using character set 'CP437'

gpg: selecting card failed: No such device

gpg: OpenPGP card not available: No such device`

Comment: Some thoughts: Can you run the `pcsc_scan` command to see if it recognizes your card reader? Based on the output of scdaemon it should. Try killing PGP agent if an instance is running presently. Also `use-agent` may be a relevant option in your gpg.conf configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the cause of the problem with the GnuPG.

When removing the AES key from the card, the error about the invalid PrKDF disappeared. The card can still *not* be used as the keys don't show up with `gpg --card-edit --expert` or in Kleopatra.

Maybe the SC-HSM versions supported are only the older ones and for the newer cards there needs to be some update for the card profile?